# Two external G Drive hard drives that have not been used for 2+ years won’t mount on my iMac

Tags: hard-drive, mac, mount

I have two external G Drives for back up on my iMac. I haven't used them in 2+ years. But now I am trying to access them to see whats on each one and they will not mount on the desktop as before.

I plug in the USB plug, plug the other end into drive and nothing happens. The drive light is lit, but nothing mounts on desktop as before.

Comment: Were these drives used on the same iMac as before? Also, if the drives a plug for a external power adapter, is that plugged in as well? It could be a low power situation where the drives need more power than your USB ports are provide and an external power adapter is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you should try:

1. Boot into Recovery Mode (on Start-Up hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and check if you can see the Drives there
2. Try another cable
3. As Jack Gould mentioned, check if there are any power adapters for the drives
4. Try connecting them to another device and see if they are shown there